# Does $df(x)/dx > 0$ implies that $df(x)d(−x) <0$?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I have a stupid question: is the following assertion always true ?

$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} > 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} < 0 $

My guess is that :

$\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} > 0 \Leftrightarrow - 1 \times \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} < 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} < 0 $

I was wondering if that was true independently of the form of $f(x)$ (especially if it was dependent on the fact that $f$ was monotonic or non-monotonic).

Thanks for your help !

Best,

Comment: what about $x^2$

Comment: What's your definition of $\partial f(x)/\partial(-x)$?

Comment: @yuanmingluo let $f(x) = x^2$, for $x>0$, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} > 0$ implying that $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} < 0$ . For  $x>0$, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} < 0$ implying that $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} > 0$ . So, if $f$ is monotonic, then $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} > 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} < 0$. If $f$ is not monotonic, it depends on the values of $x$, but for the adequate range, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ will always be of the opposite sign of  $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)}$. What do you think ?

Comment: @Thorgott $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$ is the derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ (the partial derivative in the case where $f(x,y)$).

Comment: The question was what $\partial f(x)/\partial(-x)$ is, not what $\partial f(x)/\partial x$ is. And don't just say "partial derivative with respect to $-x$", give a definition.

Comment: @Thorgott I apologize for having misread your question. I define $ \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)}  $ as : $$ - \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$$ since $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial (-x)} = -1 \times \frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x} $.

Comment: In that case, by definition, $\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial(-x)}=-\frac{\partial f(x)}{\partial x}$, so what you wrote as guess is true by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe a more "formal" way to put it: if you define $ y \triangleq -x $,
then $ x = -y $ so $ \frac{ \partial x}{ \partial y } = -1 $.
By applying the chain rule,
$$
\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial y } =
\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x } \frac{ \partial x}{ \partial y } =
\underbrace{\frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x }}_{>\,0} \cdot (-1) < 0
$$
So your guess is correct. This equivalence is independent of whether $f$
is monotonic or not. It just means that if you "climb up" $f$ when going in
the $+x$ direction at a certain point, then you'll (obviously) fall down when going the other way, i.e. the $-x$ direction. In fact, it's not just a question
of different signs; $ \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial x } $ and
$ \frac{ \partial f}{ \partial y } $ are exact opposites.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer !